# Hash string being cut off upon insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bcrypt, password-encryption

I am having a strange issue. I will post two sections of code to hopefully make my question clear. The following code creates a hash from the password the user enters and I am using hmac and bcrypt:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
    $email1 = strip_tags($_POST['email1']);
    $email2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
    $pass1 = strip_tags($_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = strip_tags($_POST['pass2']);
    // make sure no fields are blank /////
    if(trim($username) == "" || trim($email1) == "" || trim($pass1) == "" || trim($pass2) == ""){
        echo "Error: All fields are required. Please press back in your browser and try again.";
        $db = null;
        exit();
    }
    /// Make sure both email fields match /////
    if($email1 != $email2){
        echo "Your email fields do not match. Press back and try again";
        exit();
    }
    //// Make sure both password fields match ////
    else if($pass1 != $pass2){
        echo "Your password fields do not match. Press back and try again";
        exit();
    }
    //// create the hmac /////
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha512', $pass1, file_get_contents('my/path/to/key.txt'));
    //// create random bytes for salt ////
    $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    //// Create salt and replace + with . ////
    $salt = strtr(base64_encode($bytes), '+', '.');
    //// make sure our bcrypt hash is 22 characters which is the required length ////
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 22);
    //// This is the hashed password to store in the db ////
    $bcrypt = crypt($hmac, '$2y$12$' . $salt);
        echo $bcrypt;
```

This code works just fine and creates a hash that looks something like this:

> $2y$12$Oysi/5oZjF4vlUYx4PvgJ.GSpAQb7njNzSTUnEy/QOFzPxqRpHFV6

The issue I am having is after performing some error handling and then inserting the data the hashed password is being cut off. Just so you know the field that I am storing it in was originally set to VARCHAR(255), and I even changed it to TEXT but it still gets cut off. Here is the rest of the code that should be where I just echoed out the password above:

```
//// Create token for activation script ////
    $token = md5($bcrypt);
    //// query to check if email is in the db already ////
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email=:email1 LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindValue(':email1',$email1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    try{
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
            $db = null;
            exit();
    }
    //// query to check if the username is in the db already ////
    $unameSQL = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1");
    $unameSQL->bindValue('username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    try{
        $unameSQL->execute();
        $unCount = $unameSQL->rowCount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $db = null;
        exit();
    }
    ///Check if email is in the db already ////
    if($count > 0){
        echo "Sorry, that email is already in use in the system";
        $db = null;
        exit();
    }
    //// Check if username is in the db already ////
    if($unCount > 0){
        echo "Sorry, that username is already in use in the system";
        $db = null;
        exit();
    }
    try{
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, signup_date, ipaddress) VALUES (:username, :email1, :bcrypt, now(), :ipaddress)");
        $stmt2->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':email1',$email1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':bcrypt',$bcrypt,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':ipaddress',$ipaddress,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt2->execute();
        /// Get the last id inserted to the db which is now this users id for activation and member folder creation ////
        $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
        $stmt3 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO activate (user, token) VALUES ('$lastId', :token)");
        $stmt3->bindValue(':token',$token,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt3->execute();
        //// Send email activation to the new user ////
        $from = "From: Auto Resposder @ GotCode <admin@gotcode.org>";
        $subject = "IMPORTANT: Activate your gotCode account";
        $link = 'http://www.gotcode.org/activate.php?user='.$lastId.'&token='.$token.'';
        //// Start Email Body ////
        $message = "
Thanks for registering an account at gotCode.org! Were glad you decided to join us in this wacky adventure.
Theres just one last step to set up your account. Please click the link below to confirm your identity and get started.
If the link below is not active please copy and paste it into your browser address bar. See you on the site!

$link
";
        //// Set headers ////
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
        $headers .= "Content-type: textrn";
        $headers .= "From: $fromrn";
        /// Send the email now ////
        mail($email1, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f noreply@mywebsite.org');
        $db->commit();
        echo "Thanks for joining! Check your email in a few moments to activate your account so that you may log in. See you on the site!<br />$bcrypt<br />$hmac<br />$salt<br />$token"; 
        exit();
        $db = null;
        exit();
    }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $db->rollBack();
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $db = null;
            exit();
        }
}
```

The rest of the code works as well in that data is inserted to the database, and my email activation gets sent out. The problem is that now the hashed password is stored in the database looking like this:

> $2hm7KFNCFyfM

I am having a really hard time figuring out why when I just echo out the hashed password its a nice long hashed string as expected but after error checking and inserting to the database it is cut off. Maybe an extra set of eyes can spot my error? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is the column made so that you can have such a long string(length of field)?

Comment: Is your database field set up to handle that many characters?

Comment: what's the type/size of the field you're putting this into? if it's (say) varchar(16), you won't be able to store anything longer than 16 chars...

Comment: What is your column definition? I'd bet it is constrained to a max length.

Comment: Originally I had it set to varchar 255, then I even changed it to TEXT. No luck.

Comment: As you can see when I echo the success message at the bottom I placed the $bcrypt variable along with some others to see what they look like and the password is actually cut at that point just on the page and in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... All I had to do to fix this was upgrade my php version from 5.2.

To be more specific on what the problem was: For PHP < 5.3  When using the blowfish algorithm one should use

> $2a$

Greater than PHP 5.2 use

> $2y$

In other words, without updating my php version a fix for this issue would be to change this line:

```
$bcrypt = crypt($hmac, '$2y$12$' . $salt);
```

To this:

```
$bcrypt = crypt($hmac, '$2a$12$' . $salt);
```

Just in case anyone runs into this same issue :)